# Why is ajax_object.ajax_url keeps saying undefined

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress

I am new to wordpress. I created an on change event in jquery, enqueued my scripts and localized it.

When I output ajax_object.ajax_url to the console on the on change event it keeps saying undefined. But when I output it to just the ajax_object to the console I get this

```
["ajax_url", "http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php"]
```

I don't understand why it says undefined when I use ajax_object.ajax_url, its really weird. Below is my code I am using. Any help would be really appreciated

```
function myEnqueue($hook){

    if("post.php" != $hook && "post-new.php") { return; };

    wp_enqueue_script("ajax-script",plugins_url("/js/meta.js",__FILE__),["jquery"]);
    wp_localize_script("ajax-script","ajax_object",["ajax_url",admin_url("admin-ajax.php")]);
}


add_action("admin_enqueue_scripts","myEnqueue");
```

**Javascript code**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

    $("#my_plugin_field").change(function() {//the selector and event
          console.log(ajax_object);

    });

    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array('ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')));
```

Or if you want to use 5.4+ `array` syntax

```
wp_localize_script('ajax-script', 'ajax_object', ['ajax_url' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php')]);
```

Answer (score 0):

change this line

```
wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
```